# Database of surveillance camera locations

Tags: database, geolocation, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, surveillance

To get more into django programming I'm planning to create a google maps mashup, which finds routes from A to B, but avoids streets/junctions that cross public surveillance cameras' perspectives. Therfore I will create a database (probably Postgres based, because of its GIS capabilities) containing

- surveillance type (surveillance camera, speed camera, road charge camera, etc.)
- geo position
- timeout (used mainly for speed cameras)

This data will then, of course, be editable freely by the users. To start, however, I will need some data to get running. Is there any such publicly available data base containing (possibly approximate) geo position of surveillance cameras?

Comment: Just a note, MySQL has GIS capabilities too.

Comment: What, looking for a getaway path for a bank job?

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that CIA employees asked questions here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UK has a speed camera database:

http://www.speedcamerasuk.com/locationsdatabase.htm

and each council provides locations of CCTV cameras, a Google search should bring them up:

http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=cctv+camera+location&btnG=Search&meta=cr%3DcountryUK|countryGB

though they are usually listed by their street name and not a proper geolocation

Comment: Interesting this was accepted, given that Willi appears to live in Germany :-)

Comment: Just need some data to start ;-) This is, indeed, not the final answer, as you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/838782/extracting-surveillance-camera-positions-from-streetview-images

Answer (score 4):

In [openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) are surveillance cameras mapped by the users of the openstreetmap community. This maps are not exhaustive but will cover cameras that are not in other databases. I don't know how good the API is to get the position etc. of this cameras.

Answer (score 2):

You can OpenStreetMap for mapping CCTV surveillance cameras:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:man_made%3Dsurveillance

And after you add them CCTV cameras will be visable on this map:
http://osmcamera.tk/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any preferences as to location?  http://www.mediaeater.com/cameras/ has camera lists for NYC; although they list text locations and not lat/long coordinates, they do publish PDF maps, so those data may be available if you ask nicely.